# xml Resource Parser not recognizing id attribute

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I'm trying to pull out all the TextViews that have been assigned id's in an Activity in order to populate them with dynamic values.  In order to do so, I'm using an `XMLResourceParser` to go through the tags and get the id's.  Here's the code:

```
public int[] getElementIds(int layoutId, String viewType) 
  throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{
    XmlResourceParser parser = activity.getResources().getLayout(layoutId);
    LinkedList<Integer> idList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    while(parser.getEventType()!=XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT){
        parser.next();
        if(parser.getEventType()==XmlResourceParser.START_TAG){
            if(parser.getName().equals(viewType)){
            idList.add(parser.getIdAttributeResourceValue(0)); //here's the problem
            }
        }
    }
    // returns an int[] from values collected
}
```

The line with the comment just gives me back zeroes, the default value I specified. The following code, however, worked, the attribute index worked out through trial and error:

```
idList.add(parser.getAttributeResourceValue(0, 1)); // the zero here is 'id' attribute index
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After additional research, it seems that I've found a bug in the API. The code that was available online looks like this:

```
public int getIdAttributeResourceValue(int defaultValue) {
      return getAttributeResourceValue(null, "id", defaultValue);
}

public int getAttributeResourceValue(String namespace, String attribute, int defaultValue) {
       int idx = nativeGetAttributeIndex(mParseState, namespace, attribute);
       if (idx >= 0) {
           return getAttributeResourceValue(idx, defaultValue);
       }
   return defaultValue;
}

 public int getAttributeResourceValue(int idx, int defaultValue) {
       int t = nativeGetAttributeDataType(mParseState, idx);
       // Note: don't attempt to convert any other types, because
       // we want to count on appt doing the conversion for us.
       if (t == TypedValue.TYPE_REFERENCE) {
            return nativeGetAttributeData(mParseState, idx);
       }
       return defaultValue;
 }
```

Wherein the last function is the one actually doing the work. There is no documentation for this class (XMLBlock), and I have no access to the `native` functions, which are actually written in C.  What I do know is that the offending function here is the second one, with namespace and attribute name being the parameters. For attribute name 'style' it works fine, but for 'id' (which is both the name provided by the API in another place, and the value returned by a different function that returns attribute name, provided a given index), it doesn't come up with anything, and consistently spits out the default value.  Furthermore, I **can** access those same id values by using the function whose parameters are attribute index rather than name (the last function copied above).  Conclusion: something is messed up with the way the 'native' code processes the name 'id'. I'm sending a bug report to the open source project, and I'll post any response I get.

Comment: do you have the issue number, that you reported?

Comment: I can't even find the issue reporter at the moment.  But I can point you to my workaround on [github](https://github.com/jegesh/Android-simple-XML-Parser)!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I've implemented this function in my own code:

```
private int getIdAttributeResourceValue(XmlResourceParser parser) {
    final int DEFAULT_RETURN_VALUE = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < parser.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
        String attrName = parser.getAttributeName(i);
        if ("id".equalsIgnoreCase(attrName)) {
           return parser.getAttributeResourceValue(i, DEFAULT_RETURN_VALUE);
        }
    }
    return DEFAULT_RETURN_VALUE;
}
```